# Change default behavior on click for jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using jstree to create a tree without checkboxes. In such a tree a click selects one node of the tree and deselects all others. To select multiple nodes one has to do ctrl + click (as examplified by the jstree [demo](https://www.jstree.com/demo/)). Is there a way to change this default to the more similar to checkbox default, which is click to select, click again to deselect?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use the checkbox plugin that has your desired behavior by default?

Comment: Because the default behavior of checkbox doesn't allow parent nodes to be selected independently from their children. If you select a parent, all children are automatically selected, if you select all children, parent node is automatically selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with using checkboxes and your only reservation is the dependence on one another, try using the checkboxes plugin but set "three_state" to false.

From [JSTree](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox&f=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox.three_state):

> $.jstree.defaults.checkbox.three_state: a boolean indicating if checkboxes should cascade down and have an undetermined state. Defaults to true.